# Compilation error when trying to pass an Object by reference

Tags: c++, parameters, reference

Every time I try to compile this program, it gets the following error:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Character::setTime(int)", referenced from:
      awesome(Character)    in ccmsAc4F.o
  "Character::getMoney()", referenced from:
      _main in ccmsAc4F.o
  "Character::setMoney(double)", referenced from:
      awesome(Character)    in ccmsAc4F.o
  "Character::Character()", referenced from:
      _main in ccmsAc4F.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Character compiles correctly and has no errors. The problem seems to be trying to pass the object as a reference.  The following is my program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Character.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void awesome(Character& character);

int main() {
    Character userCharacter;
    awesome(userCharacter);
    cout << userCharacter.getMoney();
    return 0;
}

void awesome(Character& character)
{
    character.setTime(0);
    character.setMoney(0.00);
}
```

Does anyone have any insight on what I'm doing wrong? Ultimately in a larger program I want to use the reference to edit an already instantiated object. I'm assuming referencing is the right way to do it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you link Character.o?

Comment: Those aren't actually _compiler_ errors, they are _linker_ errors. It seems you are not building with the source file for the `Character` class.

Answer (score 1):

They are linker errors. You forget to implement methods of `Character` or link Character.o to your project.

```
Character::setTime(int) { /* body ?! */ }
Character::getMoney() { /* body ?! */ }
Character::setMoney(double) { /* body ?! */ }
Character::Character() { /* body ?! */ }
```

Comment: The methods are fully implemented. I'm not sure what you mean by linking Character.o to the project.

Comment: Did you add character.cpp to your project ot makefile?

Comment: M M, I appreciate the help. I think a better means of explanation would be how you personally would go through the process of compiling and linking this program correctly. I'm using Xcode for C++ development, and we haven't gone over anything like this in my Software Construction course.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile Character.cpp that will result Character.o which will finally link with your project that makes the class Character known to the linker.Then this linking errors will be gone.